# Proper way to determine if NSView is drawn

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Is there a proper way to determine if a `NSView` is actually drawn in the current view hierarchy or not, considering cases like:

- The view is completely offscreen (not mandatory)
- The view is not on top of the view hierarchy

The `-isHidden` and `-isHiddenOrHasHiddenAncestor` are unfortunately not set when e.g. a view disappears because a tab view switches to another tab.

The reason for this is that I have an attached child window and I would like to be able to hide it as well when the view that it is attached to is not drawn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a trick to tell if it is visible, but it requires subclassing. It works by toggling an ivar on 2 events.

```
- (void)discardCursorRects {
  isDrawn_ = NO;
  [super discardCursorRects];
}

- (void)resetCursorRects {
  isDrawn_ = YES;
  [super resetCursorRects];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whether (or when) it's drawn is supposed to be "none of your business" and really have nothing to do with whether or not it's on-screen. Use NSView's -viewDidMoveToSuperview or -viewDidMoveToWindow to manage this.

Comment: Of course it has something todo if it's drawn (on screen) or not. `-viewDidMoveToSuperview` renders itself useless when the view is e.g. in another Tab that is not active - and therefore not visible.